# How to Discern an Asyndetic Coordinate Subject Complement?

Tags: complements

> ". . .to let fall is absolute indifference, absolute contempt;"

I think this got maybe discerned an asyndetic coordinate subject complement. May something like *He was a moody man, **his temper was never equable*** seem maybe something like an asyndetic coordinate subject complement?

Comment: I think this is related to your question:- < “to let fall is”… A complete clause? What is the subject?>  -  Unfortunately your question here is not clear. Please can you rephrase it?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is it 'is this asyndeton?'? Or is it 'how does one determine an instance of asyndeton?'? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

You have an example of an asyndeton, an omission of a conjunction:

> He was a moody man *;* [**,and**] his temper was never equable.

Where the different type faces give your choices:  semicolon, asyndeton; conjunction, syndeton.

But the conjuncts are two independent clauses, not subjective complements.  If you want the latter, try this:

> He was a moody, volatile-tempered man

Comment: So may *He was a moody man, his temper was never equable.* seem like an asyndeton? And I guess asyndetic means not containing a conjunction? I think someone did text *He was a moody man, his temper was never equable.* seems mostly like two independent clauses. And maybe mostly *He was a moody man, an intemperate man.* seemed like asyndetic coordination.

Comment: That's exactly what it means from the Greek ἀ (not) + σύνδετον (connected).  Your first example is an asyndeton of independent clauses.  Place a semicolon between them instead of a comma.  Your last example is an asyndeton of subjective complements.